# hi.using super in extending

Tags: constructor, extends, super

my code is like this

```
public class B {
    public B(int f) {

    }

}


public class A extends B{

    int f=4;
    public A() {
        super(f);
    }

}
```

why does it make a compile error?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an instance of class A, Java will behave as if it **first** creates an instance of B, meaning that the constructor of the super class, super(), will be called, (or in this case, you call it yourself) and **then** "adding on" the attributes of class A.
This is also why a super() call always has to be the first instruction in a constructor.

You are trying to pass an argument, which in a sense doesn't exist yet, because you try to read f **before** you called super().

What you could do is the following:

```
public class A extends B {
    static final int F_CONST = 4;
    int f = F_CONST;

    public A() {
        super(F_CONST);
    }
}
```

Here F_CONST is a constant "static" variable, which is a "class variable", instead of an "object or instance variable". static members will be initialized when the class is loaded in memory, which is before any constructor can be called. The compiler is even allowed to replace F_CONST with just the value 4 directly, which would also be a simple solution.